OpenSSL version mismatch, SSH is failing to start
I upgraded Ubuntu 20,04 to Ubuntu 22.04. The upgrade was smooth, but I cant start the SSH service, with the error OPENSSL version mismatch: Built on 30100000, you have 30000002
Please assist and advise on openssl version I can install to resolve the issue.
I have tried so many things, with no luck.

I believe that reinstalling openssl-client and openssl-server simultaneously should help. See e.g. this answer.

It helps to help you if you tell us what you have tried and any errors or messages you get. Just saying tried many things really is no info at all.

Please edit your question to show us the complete output of apt list openssl

I was one of the cases where reinstalling openssl-client and openssl-server did not fix things. In my case, it was conda!
$ conda list | grep ssl
openssl     3.3.31     hb9d3cd8_3    conda-forge

while the system openssl (Ubuntu) was 3.0.2, triggering this error.
Easiest workaround was to unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH as conda sets that variable to the folder where conda has its package libraries.
